# Triggered send permission error

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

We have an existing triggered send and we are trying to update the template based email however we always encounter an error "You do not have permission for this operation"

We are using a user with Administrator and MArketing cloud administrator role.

[image]

Comment: Hi @MC Learner, Welcome to SFSE!. Is this Triggered send from Salesforce? If yes, then please change the email template in salesforce itself.

Comment: I would contact support. Could be something as simple as an unchecked box or something as big as a corrupted trigger. They would be your best bet at identifying the exact issue to resolve it